# dropna(axis=1)とdropna(axis=0)で出力された内容が同じになるのはなぜですか？

Tags: python3, pandas

pandasのdropnaについて質問です。一通りpandasなどをインポートした後に
今、df1のような欠損値ありのExcalデータを作って、試しています。
データは以下の通りです。

```
[In]
    df1=pd.read_excel('mo.xlsx')
    print(df1)

[Out]
      T    A    B    C
    0  2  2.0  5.0  1.0
    1  1  1.0  NaN  NaN
    2  3  NaN  2.0  NaN
```

---

### ここで、

```
[In]
    df1.dropna(inplace = True)
```

をした後に、

```
[In]
    df1.dropna(axis=0)
    print(df1.dropna(axis=0))
[Out]
       T    A    B    C
    0  2  2.0  5.0  1.0
```

また、

```
  [In]
    df1.dropna(axis=1)
    print(df1.dropna(axis=1))
  [Out]
       T    A    B    C
    0  2  2.0  5.0  1.0
```

となってしまい、"行"と"列"の削除がどちらも"行"になってしまいます。この理由についてお尋ねしたいです。また、考えられる原因があればご教授願います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df1.dropna(inplace = True)
```

した時点で2行目と3行目は削除されているので、そのあと`df1.dropna(axis=0)`しても`df1.dropna(axis=1)`しても削除される行も列もありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！この時点で削除されているのですね。助かりました。